# Is it safe to reorder objects in Realm while using DispatchQueue.main.async?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, realm

### I'm getting this crash from Crashlytics:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x0000000104edd4d0

Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0 App     0x1048994d0 HomeVM.reorder(fromIndex:)(< compiler-generated >)
...
```

Devices have about 50-100MB RAM free

I can't replicate this crash on my device.
Could it be related to Realm in some conditions, because I'm using Realm instance and objects on **async** MAIN thread, but created on main thread? Or is it safe and there is another cause?

### What's going on:

I work on the app, where user can add his favorite places (< List >FavoritePlace) and manually reorder them. It works fine. But there is also LocationManager which looks for the nearest place and if the place isn't in the first place, then it moves it there.

```swift
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            if let userLocation = locations.last {
               self?.vm.findPlace(to: userLocation)
            }
        }
}
```

I use realm and objects created on the main thread, but in DispatchQueue.main.async block. Firstly I reorder content (used to display content in tableview), then I move object in Realm list (in write transaction) and finally I call callback, so tableView.moveRow(at: fromIndex, to: toIndex) is called.

```swift
func findPlace(to: CLLocation) {

           // Get nearest place in list
           ...

           // Get index of object in list

           if let index = favoritePlaces.index(of: nearestPlace), index != 0 {
           reorder(fromIndex: index)
          }
}

func reorder(fromIndex: Int) {

        // Reorder [Content] (made from Realm List, used by tableview)

        let nearestContent = content[fromIndex]
        content.remove(at: fromIndex)
        content.insert(nearestContent, at: 0)

        // Reorder Realm list

        realm.beginWrite()
        favoritePlaces.move(from: fromIndex, to: 0)
        try? realm.commitWrite(withoutNotifying: [notificationToken!])

        // Callback to update tableview

        moveRow?(IndexPath(row: fromIndex, section: 0), IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0))

}
```

```swift
vm.moveRow = { [weak self] (fromIndex, toIndex) in
            self?.tableView.beginUpdates()
            self?.tableView.moveRow(at: fromIndex, to: toIndex)
            self?.tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Crash log doesn't tell me which problem causes the crash. It just points to the function reorder(fromIndex:). So I don't know how to solve this. Thanks for any help.

Comment: If I were attempting to replicate the error, the first thing I'd want to know is how many objects does it take to cause the crash. Once you've got that in hand, you could attempt to recreate it on your dev machine using mock objects. Absent hard data on the number, you could just write a method in a test class to generate a sufficient number of mock objects to force a crash and debug from there.

Comment: There could a number of things causing the issue - the fromIndex could be out of bounds for example. is [Content] a Realm List? What is *favoritePlaces*, a List? Did you add a breakpoint and step through the code examining the vars along they way until one is not as expected? Is there a specific line that's throwing an error? I see you're not handling errors in with your try statements - you may want to add that to not only protect your code but it may help track down errors.

Comment: @Jay You're right, I'll handle it in a better way. But I don't get why the crash log doesn't show me the reason - and only says: "EXC_BREAKPOINT" and it points to the line where reorder(fromIndex: index) is called. (So it doesn't even show the specific line inside the function). Can this be caused by a memory problem?
**To clarify:**
The content is just my Struct, favoritePlaces is a Realm List. 
This crash affects only +- 5% of users.

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: @Adrian Thanks for your comment. I don't know if it caused by specific number of objects. It happens to people who have 2 saved places as well as 10 for example. Anyway I will try to replicate the error!

Comment: *The content is just my Struct, favoritePlaces is a Realm List*  - A Realm List cannot contain a Struct, it can only contain other Realm Objects which are not structs. I would say a memory issue is unlikely if you are strictly dealing with Realm Objects as they are lazily loaded. However, if you are 'converting' them to structs, arrays etc, it could be. Can you clarify the question; include the objects that populate the content array as well as whatever is in favorite places?

Comment: @Jay Yes, I’m converting them. From **FavoritePlace** (contains name, ID..) I make struct **Content** (name, color, distance and other properties to be displayed). So tableview uses array [content]. When I want to reorder them, I firstly reorder [content], then List and then call tableview to move its rows.  —> So probably this is the possible source of crash? Inconsistency of List and [content]?

Comment: That can absolutely cause the crash. If you have 10,000 Realm Objects in a Result, those are lazily loaded so they are only in memory when accessed, so it could only be a few Kb of memory. However, if those are all 'converted' to structs then all 10,000 are hanging out in memory which is a significantly larger footprint. Not sure if that's the entire issue but you may want to consider some type of pagination strategy for the ones converted to structs, or maybe even leverage the Results object itself as your dataSource.